What's the surface area of an $n$-dimensional lemniscate?
Question
What is the surface area of n-dimensional lemniscate?
$$\bigg(\sum_{m=1}^n x_m^2\bigg)^2 = x_1^2 -\sum_{m=2}^n x_m^2  $$
Exposition

The lemniscate $(x^2+y^2)^2=(x^2-y^2)$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ both are in the picture above.
The lemniscate has area $1$ and perimeter $2\bar{\omega}:=2\int_0^1 (1-x^4)^{-1/2}dx \approx 5.2441150929 $.
Pursuing the analogy between $\bar\omega$ and $\pi$ we can find (in Wikipedia's "Lemniscate constant" entry) that they both have infinite series representations and both are demonstrably transcendental (in fact, they are algebraically independent). A lovely chart and formula for the n-sphere's surface area and volume appear in Wikipedia's "Unit sphere" entry, and I wonder if these things are achievable for the lemniscate as well.
Future questions might include Diophantine approximations of $\bar\omega$ and questions about how they're connected: Is it possible to prove a claim like "If $\pi$ has property $\phi$ then so does $\bar\omega$." I was thinking $\pi$ is normal if and only if $\bar\omega$ is normal.

I don't have a closed form answer but I reduced the problem to a one-dimensional integral.
In polar coordinates,
$$
x_1 = r \cos \theta_1,\quad x_2=r\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2,\quad \ldots ,\quad x_{n-1} = r \sin\theta_1 \cdots \sin\theta_{n-2} \cos\theta_{n-1},\quad x_n = r \sin\theta_1 \cdots \sin\theta_{n-2} \sin\theta_{n-1},
$$
the $(n-1)$-lemniscate is given by
$$
r^2 = \cos 2\theta_1,
$$
which is independent of $\theta_2,\ldots,\theta_{n-1}$. In other words, the $(n-1)$-lemniscate is axially symmetric about the $x_1$ axis (which is already evident from the original equation in Cartesian coordinates). Note that this equation has a solution if and only if $\theta_1$ is in the interval $I=[0,\pi/4] \cup [3\pi/4,\pi]$. So the area of the $(n-1)$-lemniscate can be written as
$$
\int_I s(n-2)(r(\theta_1)\sin \theta_1)^{n-2} \sqrt{r(\theta_1)^2 + r’(\theta_1)^2} d\theta_1 = 2 s(n-2) \int_0^{\pi/4} (1-2\sin^2\theta_1)^{(n-3)/2}(\sin \theta_1)^{n-2} d\theta_1,
$$
where $s(k)$ is the area of the unit $k$-sphere; e.g., $s(0)=2$, $s(1)=2\pi$, $s(2)=4\pi$, etc.
All that's left to do is to calculate this one-dimensional integral. One can use a CAS such as Mathematica to do it. For odd $n$, there are no square roots in the integrand, so the answer is in terms of radicals (in fact, a rational linear combination of $1$ and $\sqrt 2$). On the other hand, for even $n$, the answer is in terms of complete elliptic integrals.
